# Stacking UI elements and Tracking Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have many rectangles(Cards) (Technically a Rect class along with a ShapeDrawable inside it) and they are stacked on top of one another or should be kept on the sides..They should respond to touch and zoom events.

For example,

Here the card that is shaded is below and the rest are above it.The card 2 & 3 Partially hides it.When I touch the one below it should come Up.

How should I design my cards or shaded rectangles.Should I use a custom view or View group.(I am new to android and I am not sure how to implement this.Is this even a good Idea.Can we have so many of them on the screen?)

As of now I have created a stack which stores a list of such objects and have created an another inner class which SurfaceView  and I am accessing the above stack to draw all my elements.But now the problem is that I have to map all my touch events to each of those cards or rectangles.Although this is possible i was wondering was there a better way to do that.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic idea how to write kind of code from [CardUIExample](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/). They have developed kind of such useful thing.

Comment: Hi, The CardUIExample maintains a stack as the total number of cards that are present on the screen is limited.! However I think I should explore the code more throughly to see how the each event on the card is handled. .Thanks @AndroidVogue

Comment: @SreeAurovindh Code is there so you can modify it according to your needs.